# Screen goes black with cursor, Nvidia problem?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have a strange behavior of my system since some days. When doing normal operation, the monitor goes black showing only a cursor, the fan start to spin and then there is nothing I could do to get back to work.
I have included my journal here.  I suspect that this is due to Nvidia driver problems, in fact you can see:

```
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap nvidia-sleep.sh[12585]: /usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh: line 20: echo: write error: Input/output error
```

But please, have a look at everything that happens.  This is the journal at the time of the problem, I have included only the time close to the event:

```
Sep 29 07:32:24 student-cap systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Sep 29 07:32:24 student-cap anacron[11550]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-09-29
Sep 29 07:32:24 student-cap anacron[11550]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Sep 29 07:32:24 student-cap systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 29 07:33:16 student-cap wpa_supplicant[893]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-61 noise=9999 txrate=48000
Sep 29 07:33:18 student-cap wpa_supplicant[893]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-53 noise=9999 txrate=54000
Sep 29 07:33:18 student-cap wpa_supplicant[893]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-48 noise=9999 txrate=48000
Sep 29 07:33:19 student-cap wpa_supplicant[893]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-49 noise=9999 txrate=54000
Sep 29 07:34:27 student-cap wpa_supplicant[893]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-49 noise=9999 txrate=48000
Sep 29 07:35:02 student-cap systemd[1]: Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Sep 29 07:35:02 student-cap nvidia-persistenced[1169]: Received signal 15
Sep 29 07:35:02 student-cap nvidia-persistenced[1169]: Socket closed.
Sep 29 07:35:02 student-cap nvidia-persistenced[1169]: PID file unlocked.
Sep 29 07:35:02 student-cap nvidia-persistenced[1169]: PID file closed.
Sep 29 07:35:02 student-cap nvidia-persistenced[1169]: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
Sep 29 07:35:02 student-cap nvidia-persistenced[1169]: Shutdown (1169)
Sep 29 07:35:02 student-cap systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 29 07:35:02 student-cap systemd[1]: Stopped NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service:9: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/teamviewerd.pid → /run/teamviewerd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service:9: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/teamviewerd.pid → /run/teamviewerd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system hibernate actions...
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap hibernate[12578]: nvidia-hibernate.service
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap logger[12578]: <13>Sep 29 07:35:03 hibernate: nvidia-hibernate.service
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap suspend[12579]: nvidia-resume.service
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap logger[12579]: <13>Sep 29 07:35:03 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system resume actions.
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap suspend[12583]: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap logger[12583]: <13>Sep 29 07:35:03 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event15 - Video Bus: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "50"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "51"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event7  - DaKai 2.4G RX: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "52"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event8  - DaKai 2.4G RX Mouse: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "53"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event9  - DaKai 2.4G RX System Control: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "54"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "55"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event14 - BisonCam,NB Pro: BisonCam,NB Pr: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "56"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event5  - FTCS1000:01 2808:0102 Mouse: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "57"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event6  - FTCS1000:01 2808:0102 Touchpad: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "58"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event13 - Intel HID events: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "59"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "60"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event12 - ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (**) Option "fd" "54"
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) event10 - DaKai 2.4G RX Consumer Control: device removed
Sep 29 07:35:03 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (EE) modeset(0): Failed to set CTM property: -13
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: Permission denied
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:79
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:74
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:77
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:76
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:73
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:78
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[8566]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap nvidia-sleep.sh[12585]: /usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh: line 20: echo: write error: Input/output error
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap systemd[1]: nvidia-hibernate.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system hibernate actions.
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 29 07:35:04 student-cap systemd[1]: Failed to start NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Sep 29 07:35:09 student-cap acpid[844]: client 8566[1000:1000] has disconnected
Sep 29 07:35:33 student-cap systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 29 07:35:33 student-cap systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Sep 29 07:35:33 student-cap systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Consumed 4min 9.510s CPU time.
Sep 29 07:37:33 student-cap systemd-logind[890]: Power key pressed.
Sep 29 07:37:33 student-cap systemd-logind[890]: Power key pressed.
```

I found something on the Nvidia forum but I am unable to fix my system (although, I am not 100% sure it is related):
[https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cant-wake-up-from-suspend-hibernate-need-help/177205][1]

Any help please?

Edit:  Sorry, important information regarding my ubuntu version were missing.

```
$ uname -r 
6.2.0-33-generic
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: @guiverc thank you for the comment.  I have edited the post.  I hope the information I have put are enough.  Please, let me know if I have correctly interpreted your request.

Comment: I'm having this issue exactly as described. Ubuntu 23.04, though. my gut says this is nvidia related, but I haven't found anything other than the "nvidia-sleep.sh" error